# Wordpress have index.php and single.php show the same content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom blog page. `www.example.com/blog`

In `index.php` I have put all the code to show the blog posts. When a user clicks on one of the blog items it goes to `single.php`. The code in `single.php` is an exact copy of `index.php`.

How can I have index.php or single.php call the other so that I don't need to copy/paste the same code to two files every time I make an edit (if I can even remember to do that).

Comment: That's called "importing or "including" code. You might want to read the PHP documentation and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using WordPress correctly.

In your case I would create a shortcode, and place it wherever you want.

There's some [shortcode info here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Clean up index.php and single.php, and use the WP admin to create pages/posts with that shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you Look in the codex for hierarchy of files...you will see that the Index.php will used for single.php when no Single.php is available.

So if you have exactly the same Code for both, just delete the Single.php